# Using Python How To Insert Data To Sap Hana Table

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-insert, hana

I connected sap hana table while inserting data to hana table getting below error

**Error inserting data: (260, 'invalid column name: LOADDT')**

Below is the insert query using python

```
 tgt_query = '''
INSERT INTO "SAPCUSTOM"."GEL.Apps.Tech::tbl.IBDlyTrend"(LoadDt,FisWeek,InbeVol,Outbol6WCH,Outol6WWC) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
'''
val = (LoadDt,FisWeek,InbeVol,Outbol6WCH,Outol6WWC)
try:
    cur.execute(tgt_query, val)
    #conn.commit() 
    conn.commit()
    print('inserted successfully')                    
except Exception as e:
    print("Error inserting invalid email:", e)
```

in Hana table column name is  **LoadDt** only but why it is showing invalid column i didn't understand

Please suggest your ideas i'm new to this sap hana

If i use %s in values getting % syntax error

```
tgt_query = '''INSERT INTO "SAPCUSTOM"."GEL.Apps.Tech::tbl.IBDlyTrend"(LoadDt,FiscalWeek,InboundCaseVol,OutboundCaseVol6WCH,OutboundCaseVol6WWC) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) '''
```

Error : **Error inserting data: (257, 'sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "%": line 1 col 154 (at pos 154)')**

Not sure why it is giving 2 different errors invalid column and syntax near

please help me out anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `LoadDt` cannot be found, because its actual name contains lower case characters. Adding double-quotes (`"LoadDt"`) should help you out here. When not using quotes, HANA will assume that the name is upper case. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405086/hana-newbie-why-do-my-field-names-need-to-be-quoted) for more details.

The syntax error indicates, that Python does not replace your string placeholders correctly. This is, in a way, unrelated to the database. It is evident, that you cannot simply replace the SQL placeholders (`?`) by Python placeholders (`%s`) without further changes to the code. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-a-python-format-string) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @https://stackoverflow.com/users/16739843/mathias-kemeter it worked "LoadDt"